# Pic upload options Gallery and Camera : when a button clicked , react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hi Guys I need to create a button component that will give options 1) choose pics from Gallery 2) take photo from camera  and I want to be able to access the cameraComponent described here: https://github.com/expo/camerja , (App.js of this is renamed as CameraScreen) my parent component App.js looks as below  -which has a camera button but does nothing when clicked

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,WebView ,Button} from 'react-native';
import CameraScreen from './CameraScreen';



export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>

        <Button onPress = {CameraScreen} title="Camera"
  color="#841584"
  accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"></Button>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't giving a function to the onPress prop and you missed the tags for the CameraScreen component.

Try this: 
First create a function that returns the CameraScreen component

```
renderCamera(){ 
 return( <CameraScreen /> );
}
```

Then bind it to the onPress prop:

```
onPress={this.renderCamera().bind(this)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use react-native-image-picker and call it onClick. It opens camera easily. [react-native-image-picker](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-image-picker)

Image-picker has following options -

1. Capture Image from camera
2. Image from gallery

Also if you want any other options you can pass it